# is defining size of arrays as a variable enter by user legal?

Tags: c, arrays

I thought size of arrays should be constant.I code in VS 2019 and even when I do something like this:

```
    const int size = 5;
    int number[size];
```

I will receive this error `expression must have a constant value` ,only alternative for using an integer directly for array size ,is using `macro define` ,otherwise I will receive error.

But in some IDEs like `dev` ,it is even possible to took size of array as input from user.I also saw people code's here with user defined array size.

So here is my problem :

is it right ,to do this? are there risks and problem for user defined array size?

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure, because I checked some of similar question like this ,but since they were about `c++` there answers is about `c++` too.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the `c` tag before.

Comment: Search for VLA, Variable Lenght Arrays. They are allowed in C though recent revisiobs made the optional (=potentially unsupported). I'm pretty sure that this info is already covered by a question, but I cannot look for it right now.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni it's all my fault not to search well ,but since most of questions I found with this topic were `c++` so I decided to ask it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable-length arrays (VLAs) are [legal from C99 onwards](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array), although some compilers like GCC will allow them as an extension in older versions too. From C11 onwards, compilers are no longer required to support VLAs and will define `__STDC_NO_VLA__` as `1` if they don't support it.

VLAs are inherently risky: either you know the maximum size of your data beforehand, in which case you can allocate a fixed-length array, or you don't, in which case you run the risk of overflowing the stack.

It's worth noting that in C++, variable-length arrays were never part of the standard.

Comment: VLAs were turned optional in C11

Comment: Perhaps due to influence from MS who have never implemented them.

Comment: @WeatherVane How do you know that?

Comment: @ArdentCode because MSVC compiler rejects `int n = 42; char arr[n];` . Or the grapevine ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane So is MSVC the only such compiler? You have accused Microsoft without evidence, I'll report you when I get a job there lol

Comment: @ArdentCode you only need evidence in answers. Good luck with the new job.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why do you take the 'r' away? Your printf is not working properly lol as you said earlier check the return value ;)

Comment: @WhetherVain New job? See my developer story :( As of now, I'm just messing around here :P

Comment: @ArdentCoder glad you get the pun.

Comment: @WhetherVain haha nice to meet you :)

Comment: @ArdentCoder I read that about VLAs somewhere, can't find it sorry.

Answer (score -2):

At least in C, `const` has more the meaning "read-only" than constant.
In C you can use an enumertaion member. The members are treated as constants.

```
enum { size = 5 };
int number[size];
```

This works.